# Cannot install python 3.10.10, mysql and anything else (libaio)

Tags: dependencies, python-3.10

My system it's seems broken. I can't install one of the latest python, tkinter or mysql-client. The issue is the next:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnss3-dev : Depends: libnss3 (= 2:3.49.1-1ubuntu1.9) but 2:3.49.1-1ubuntu1.6 is to be installed
               Depends: libnspr4-dev (>= 4.6.6-1) but it is not going to be installed
 libsqlite3-dev : Depends: libsqlite3-0 (= 3.31.1-4ubuntu0.5) but 3.31.1-4ubuntu0.3 is to be installed
 libssl-dev : Depends: libssl1.1 (= 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.17) but 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16 is to be installed
 zlib1g-dev : Depends: zlib1g (= 1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1.5) but 1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1.3 is to be installed
 zoom : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libegl1-mesa but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libxcb-xtest0 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

--> $ uname -a
Linux asus 5.8.0-43-generic #49~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 5 09:57:56 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
--> $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

Option --fix-broken does not help. Please, advise

Comment: Try installing the dependencies first, which are mentioned in output messages.

Comment: For instance when I tried to install 

sudo apt install build-essential zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev libssl-dev libreadline-dev libffi-dev libsqlite3-dev wget libbz2-dev 

I've got exact the same. Nothing helps

Comment: I don't understand what's happen at all. Any actions are broken. Doesn't work, can't say more:

~$ sudo apt install python3.10
~$ sudo apt install python3.10-minimal
~$ sudo apt install mysql-client

Answer (score 0):

These commands fix the issue:

```
sudo dpkg -r zoom
sudo apt-get --fix-broken install libxcb-xtest0
sudo apt policy libegl-dev
sudo dpkg -r libegl-dev libgl-dev
sudo apt-get --fix-broken install libgles1 libegl-dev libgl-dev libglx0 libegl1-mesa-dev libglx-dev libglvnd-dev libgles-dev libopengl-dev
```

Setup is running.

Comment: If you have information to add to your question, edit it and add it there. The edit link is below the tags in the lower left corner of your question.